Pardot API V4 returning 302 status code in Production but not Sandbox
I'm using the Pardot API to update prospects, and it works perfectly in the sandbox. However, in production, I get a status code 302 (redirection). I have tested a GET of the instance and that is returning a value so I think the authentication is correct. Here's the code snippet I'm using to update prospect score:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Flow_to_Pardot_API_Credential/api/prospect/version/4/do/batchUpdate');
req.setHeader('Pardot-Business-Unit-Id', '0Uvxxxxxxxxxx');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody('prospects=<prospects><prospect><fid>00QTexxxxxxxx</fid><score>55</score></prospect><prospects>');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
//Ideally you would parse the JSON response and work with it
System.debug(res.getBody());

Any idea why I am getting this error? I feel like the Endpoint is incorrect but I tried to debug the result header location and it is null. And the documentation says this is the correct endpoint.

What is the domain name?
For example, if you're calling sitename.lightning.force.com but it wants sitename.my.salesforce.com, you'll get a 302.
